# Can't open my scracthorg: "No AuthInfo found for name myscracthorg"

Tags: salesforcedx

1. I logged in my dev org:
   sfdx force:auth:web:login -a dev-hub --setdefaultdevhubusername
2. Then I created a new scratchorg:
   sfdx force:org:create -f config/project-scratch-def.json --setalias scratchorg4 --durationd days 30  --targetdevhubusername myusername@gmail.com
3. I pushed my changes to my new scratchorg:
   sfdx force:source:push -u myscratchorg
4. When I try to open i receive an error:
   sfdx force:org:open -u myscracthorg
   sfdx force:org:open -u myscracthorg
   ERROR running force:org:open:  No AuthInfo found for name myscracthorg

Command sfdx force:org:list returns successfull result, I have 2 scratch orgs.

I tried to delete all my scratch orgs and repeated all steps from the begining but no success.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: Is that because create org uses **scratchorg4** as alias and  open org uses **myscracthorg** as alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the script you provided you created Scratch Org with alias 'scratchorg4', but then you're trying to open 'myscracthorg'. Try running `sfdx force:org:list` to display list of your Scratch Orgs

Side Note. You use 3 different aliases:
- scratchorg4 for creation
- myscratchorg for push
- myscracthorg for openning

probably typos. If this is one bash/cmd script set org value to some variable or just add `-s` param so org:create, so this Scratch Org will be used by default if no username is specified

Comment: Yes, thanks. The problem was in typos.